Combining Regex and Non-Regex in the same function
I have a dataframe:
mydf <- data.frame(
  col1 = c("54", "abc", "123", "54 abc", "zzz", "a", "99"),
  col2 = c("100", "200", "300", "400", "500", "600", "700"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

In this dataframe, I want to replace all elements with NA unless they meet one of these conditions:

strictly a number (e.g. "54" keep, "54 abc" discard)
belong to target_string

I was not sure how to do this in R using apply, so I tried to write a loop:
target_string <- c("a", "zzz")

replace_with_na_old <- function(df, target_string) {
  for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    for (j in 1:ncol(df)) {
      value <- df[i, j]
      if (!grepl("^[0-9]+$", value) && !(value %in% target_string)) {
        df[i, j] <- NA
      }
    }
  }
  return(df)
}

mydf_cleaned_old <- replace_with_na_old(mydf, target_string)

Is there another way to do this?
Note: Here is how to replace %in% with %like%:
   replace_with_na_new <- function(df, target_string) {
  for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    for (j in 1:ncol(df)) {
      value <- df[i, j]
      if (!grepl("^[0-9]+$", value) && !any(sapply(target_string, function(pattern) grepl(pattern, value)))) {
        df[i, j] <- NA
      }
    }
  }
  return(df)
}


You already have the necessary logic to check this, all you need is to vectorize it.
replace_with_na <- function(value, target_string) {
  value[!(grepl('^\\d+$', value) | value %in% target_string)] <- NA
  value
}

Now you can apply this function for each column using any of the apply* functions in base R.
new_df <- mydf
new_df[] <- lapply(mydf, replace_with_na, target_string)
new_df

#  col1 col2
#1   54  100
#2 <NA>  200
#3  123  300
#4 <NA>  400
#5  zzz  500
#6    a  600
#7   99  700

Or if you prefer dplyr we can use across for similar result.
library(dplyr)
mydf %>% mutate(across(everything(), \(x) replace_with_na(x, target_string)))


You can replace all elements that do not belong to the target_string and that contain not-digit characters.
mydf[sapply(mydf, \(x) grepl("\\D", x) & !x %in% target_string)] = NA

 col1 col2
1   54  100
2 <NA>  200
3  123  300
4 <NA>  400
5  zzz  500
6    a  600
7   99  700


A variant might be is.na(mydf) <- vapply(mydf, \(x) grepl("\\D", x) & !x %in% target_string, logical(nrow(mydf)))

You can generate the regex pattern in advance and then apply grepl, e.g.,
patt <- sprintf(
  "^\\d+$|%s",
  paste0(sprintf("\\b%s\\b", target_string), collapse = "|")
)
list2DF(lapply(mydf, \(x) replace(x, !grepl(patt, x), NA)))

which gives
  col1 col2
1   54  100
2 <NA>  200
3  123  300
4 <NA>  400
5  zzz  500
6    a  600
7   99  700


In the given example this will work but a problem might be when the target_string contains something what a regex will interpret e.g. .. Maybe use in addition stringr::str_escape.

@GKi thanks for pointing that out! Yes, my code will be in trouble if dealing with something like .. In that case, I admit that the other two play more robust and secure then mine.
